# Sort Core Data alphabetically with special characters

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, sorting

I have an entity in Core Data containing a lot names. Some of the names has special characters in them, i.e Åfjord. The names starting with the letter Å, needs to be at the bottom of my tableview, because it's the last letter in the norwegian alphabet.

```
-(NSArray *)getFetchedObjects:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context entityName:(NSString *)entityName sortKey:(NSString *)key{
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

if (key != nil) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:key ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescs = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescs];
}

return [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

}

And I call the method like so:

```
places = [jsonMethods fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"Places" withPredicate:nil context:self.context  sortKey:@"name"];
```

The output is:

```
 AAAA
 AAAA
 ÅÅÅÅ
 BBBB
 BBBB
 ... and so on
```

I tried to a selector to the NSSortDescriptor like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:key ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

But that just put the names starting with Å at the top

Like I said, I need to have the names starting with Å at the bottom.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think an NSPredicate should be more appropriate in this scenario.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Can you help me with how the code should be? I googled around, and haven't found anything yet.